# Android - Navigating through USSD menu using pre-determined inputs

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am planning to create an Android App that will automate sending a users response to a USSD Menu. At a click of a button, the app will send the initial code, followed by the rest of the menu inputs.

For example, the initial number is *665#, followed by 1(Make a transfer), (target number), (Password), and offer want to transfer. I'd like to be able to automate that sequence of inputs so that the user won't have to input it on their own.
PS: I dont want to make the ussd code like *665*1*targetnymber*passwd*numoffer#
because the offers varies that's why
I know that in Android Oreo, they implemented a USSD Callback using the TelephonyManager, where the Android App can send a USSD Request, and then read the response given.

I have tried only the single code can be executed
and I want the pop ups in dialing ussd comes in my app not by default phone pop up

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.